# AcceptEx() synchronous completion?

Tags: network-programming, winsock, winsock2, iocp

I am using IO completion ports and `AcceptEx()` whilst learning about servers, and am studying [Len Holgate](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7925/len-holgate)'s free server framework to do this.  He has the following code:

```
// Basically calls AcceptEx() via a previously obtained function pointer
if (!CMSWinSock::AcceptEx(
      m_listeningSocket,
      pSocket->m_socket,
      reinterpret_cast<void*>(const_cast<BYTE*>(pBuffer->GetBuffer())),
      bufferSize,
      sizeOfAddress,
      sizeOfAddress,
      &bytesReceived,
      pBuffer))
   {
      const DWORD lastError = ::WSAGetLastError();

      if (ERROR_IO_PENDING != lastError)
      {
         Output(_T("CSocketServerEx::Accept() - AcceptEx: ") + GetLastErrorMessage(lastError));

         pSocket->Release();           
         pBuffer->Release();
      }
   }
   else
   {
      // Accept completed synchronously. We need to marshal the data recieved over to the 
      // worker thread ourselves...

      m_iocp.PostStatus((ULONG_PTR)m_listeningSocket, bytesReceived, pBuffer);
   }
```

I am confused about the "Accept completed synchronously" else-case.  I have tried many times to get this code path to be hit (by pausing the code before I issue the `AcceptEx`, connecting, then resuming the code), but whenever I try the call always fails with `ERROR_IO_PENDING` and I get my notification packet.  Furthermore, I have read [this MS knowledgebase article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/192800/info-design-issues-when-using-iocp-in-a-winsock-server) (which I may have misinterpreted) which states

> Additionally, if a Winsock2 I/O call returns SUCCESS or IO_PENDING, it
>   is guaranteed that a completion packet will be queued to the IOCP when
>   the I/O completes

However, I am thinking this doesn't apply to `AcceptEx()` because the [dox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737524%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for `AcceptEx()` states of the parameter `lpdwBytesReceived`

> This parameter is set only if the operation completes synchronously.

So it seems it *can* complete synchronously...can someone tell me **how** `AcceptEx()` can complete synchronously (i.e. how I can replicate it in my server?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Additionally, if a Winsock2 I/O call returns `SUCCESS` or `ERROR_IO_PENDING`, it
>   is guaranteed that a completion packet will be queued to the IOCP when
>   the I/O completes

this is apply for **any** I/O request if completion port is associated with the file. but begin from windows vista this also depend from [notification mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365538(v=vs.85).aspx) set for a file handle.

but need first begin look from native view.

by default, if `FILE_SKIP_COMPLETION_PORT_ON_SUCCESS` not set, exist 3 case by returned `NTSTATUS status` :

1. `NT_SUCCESS(status)` or `status >= 0` - will be completion
2. `NT_ERROR(status)` or `status >= 0xc0000000` - will be no completion
3. `NT_WARNING(status) or status < 0xc0000000` - unclear - if this
   error from I/O manager (say - `STATUS_DATATYPE_MISALIGNMENT` - will
   be no completion). if this error from driver (say
   `STATUS_NO_MORE_FILES` - will be completion).

the win32 layer usually separate check for `STATUS_PENDING` and return `ERROR_IO_PENDING` in this case (but exist and exceptions, like `ReadDirectoryChangesW`). otherwise in case `NT_ERROR(status)` api return fail and set error code. otherwise return success. visible that case `NT_WARNING(status)` considered as success, but in this case, if error from I/O manager, will be no completion. I/O usually return errors from `NT_ERROR(status)` range, if parameters is incorrect. only case which i know (for asynchronous api) - `STATUS_DATATYPE_MISALIGNMENT` can be returned in case wrong aligned buffers, when I/O manager have special knowledge about buffer align. in `NtNotifyChangeDirectoryFile`
 (`ReadDirectoryChangesW` for win32) or `NtQueryDirectoryFile` (no corresponded win32 api). so only case which i know when will be no completion, when win32 return success - call `ReadDirectoryChangesW` with unaligned *lpBuffer*  (it must be DWORD-aligned ) - in this case I/O manager just return `STATUS_DATATYPE_MISALIGNMENT` but win32 layer interpret this as success code and return true. but will be no completion in this case. however this is rarely case and you probably need use wrong align structures for this. so in general yes:

by default if I/O call returns `SUCCESS` or `ERROR_IO_PENDING` will be queued a completion entry to the port. (*with special exception case which i try describe*)

if we set `FILE_SKIP_COMPLETION_PORT_ON_SUCCESS` on file object (note this is per file object but not per file handle - documentation not exactly here) all become much more simply and efficient - completion entry will be queue to the port - when and only when I/O request return `STATUS_PENDING`. `ERROR_IO_PENDING` from win32 view (except `ReadDirectoryChangesW` (*maybe some else api ?*) where win32 layer simply lost return code information)

> However, I am thinking this doesn't apply to `AcceptEx()`

you mistake. this, how i say, apply to any io request. "This parameter is set only if the operation completes synchronously." - and so what ?

---

if look to code snippet, clear visible that code assume - in case `AcceptEx` completed synchronous and no error occurs - will be no io completion. or `SetFileCompletionNotificationModes(m_listeningSocket, FILE_SKIP_COMPLETION_PORT_ON_SUCCESS)` called or code is wrong - will be io completion in this case and not need `m_iocp.PostStatus` - this is fatal error will be. however i doubt that code used `FILE_SKIP_COMPLETION_PORT_ON_SUCCESS` - so it wrong.  but error never raised because driver side implementation of `AcceptEx` (underlining ioctl) never return `STATUS_SUCCESS`: it check parameters - if it wrong - just return some error, otherwise always return `STATUS_PENDING`. as result, for asynchronous sockets `AcceptEx` never return true and code never jump to error else case. but anyway code is wrong. also i think design not the best - in case we determinate will be no completion - better just direct call completion routine with returned error code instead `Release()` (this will be done in completion routine) or `PostStatus` - for what post ?! - call direct.

---

> how `AcceptEx()` can complete synchronously

very easy - if `m_listeningSocket` is handle to **synchronous** file object. however in this case you can not bind IOCP to file (it can be bind only in case asynchronous file object).

---

about `lpdwBytesReceived` parameter - system copy `Information` member of [`IO_STATUS_BLOCK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/ns-wdm-_io_status_block) or if want `OVERLAPPED.InternalHigh`, in case operation is completed just. in case pending returned - this data simply not ready and not filled. you got actual number of bytes returned by io in completion